# Custom development of product configurator

Tags: configurable-product, development

I am looking to develop an extension to be applied on Magento website and Mobile App (IOS and Android) as the following :

- Client must choose the character that will appear wearing the shirt (he must choose the character like Arabic, European, African, .....)  so let me know if you consider this in the tasks

  1. Admin will create custom options (fabric, fit, collar, cuff, initials) for each product.
  2. Admin will be able to upload images for above each custom option.
  3. We will display the images for each custom options on front-end.
  4. The product would be configurable so the customer will select from all alternatives available for each custom option
  5. Customer can zoom in/zoom out the designed image and can rotate on 360 degree view.
  6. Once customer is done with design part then he/she can review the complete design in pop-up.
  7. After that customer can proceed to checkout.
  8. Once order is placed then admin can view the design attached with order and download the PDF/JPG/PNG.

Note 1 : How will the admin  upload the images for shirts to use in 360 degree view.

- how many images for each product should the admin upload to have 360 degree view ??
- should the admin upload only images to one model and then can apply changes in the fabric, collar, cuff, initials on this model ??  Or should he upload images for each shirt as a stand alone shirt ??
- What about having 2 images for the model ; one for the front and other for the back and make some kind of switching ??
- If the admin will upload images for one model to be applied on other choices, how can we show extra features on this model, when he changes the collar as example, how can we show this change on the model . Does that mean that we have to upload two images here ??

  Note 2 : There would be two images for each custom options (one for display the custom option and other for shirt to display how product will look like).

Finally, will this module be used as extension to be applied on Magento E-Commerce website and also Mobile App (IOS and android) ? will you support us in this ?

Comment: If you are looking for product configurator then here is the one

https://www.codedecorator.com/magento-2-product-configurator.html